# Error installing needed libraries for Steam

Tags: games, steam, 32-bit, libraries

So I installed Steam from the steampowered.com download.  Now that Steam's installed, when I try to run it I get the following:

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
[sudo] password for phil:
...............................................................................................................................
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
cups : Depends: libc-bin (>= 2.13)
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libdrm-intel1:i386 (>= 2.4.48) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (>= 2.4.31) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libelf1:i386 (>= 0.142) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libexpat1:i386 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libllvm3.4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.6) but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                libtxc-dxtn0:i386
libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic : Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3)
                    Depends: libx11-6:i386 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libx11-xcb1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxcb-dri2-0:i386 (>= 1.8) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxcb-dri3-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxcb-glx0:i386 (>= 1.8) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxcb-present0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxcb-sync1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxcb1:i386 (>= 1.9.2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxdamage1:i386 (>= 1:1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxfixes3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxshmfence1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxxf86vm1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libudev1:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                             libudev0:i386 but it is not installable
                    Conflicts: libgl1
libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic : Conflicts: libgl1:i386
                          Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
xserver-xorg-lts-utopic : Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 0~)
                       Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (>= 0~)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
Press return to continue:
```

If I press return, I get a Steam error box saying "You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6".  Pressing OK leads to a Fatal Error message from Steam saying "Failed to load steamui.so".

So I figured I should run the 'sudo apt-get -f install' command like suggested, but when I do I see the following:

```
phil@Charles:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for phil: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc-bin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc-bin
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,168 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,529 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

So that's where I'm at.  I'm kind of a novice at Linux in general, so if I've overlooked something obvious or left out important information, please let me know and I'll fill in the blanks.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting similar errors but no one seems to have any answers!

Comment: @uzi3k I don't know if this will exactly fix your system, but I found [this forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11767830&postcount=19) that at least allowed me to run apt-get -f install without getting errors.